SignalR - You are using a version of the client that isn't compatible with the server. Client version 1.5, server version undefined, Please check
I'm using SignalR in my project (asp.net and react js).
Here in C# I'm using (.net 4.8)
Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client

Version - 1.2.2.0
Runtime version - v4.0.30319

Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core

Version - 2.2.3.0
Runtime version - v4.0.30319

Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin

Version - 1.2.2.0
Runtime version - v4.0.30319

Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SystemWeb

Version - 2.2.3.0

In react I'm using these script in index.html
In jquerySignalR.js this is being used ASP.NET SignalR JavaScript Library v2.2.3
Getting this error:
Could not Connect!Error: You are using a versio
code to connect signalR from frontend 

startHub(self) {
        if ($.connection && $.connection.hub && $.connection.userNotificationHub) {
            $.connection.hub.url = Util.url + 'signalr';
            $.connection.hub.logging = true;

            $.connection.userNotificationHub.client.onLogoutCustomMessage = self.onLogoutCustom;
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function (connection) {
                console.log('Service Started', connection.id);
            }).fail(function (a) {
                console.log('Could not Connect! simult' + a);
            });
        }
        else {
            setTimeout(function () { self.startHub(self) }, 500);
        }
    }


In the backend in startup.cs I have

using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Cors;
using Owin;
using System;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Volza.Startup))]
namespace Volza
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            GlobalHost.Configuration.DisconnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3600);
            //app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            //app.MapSignalR();
            // Any connection or hub wire up and configuration should go here
            app.Map("/signalr", map =>
            {
                // Setup the CORS middleware to run before SignalR.
                // By default this will allow all origins. You can 
                // configure the set of origins and/or http verbs by
                // providing a cors options with a different policy.
                //map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
                var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
                {
                    // You can enable JSONP by uncommenting line below.
                    // JSONP requests are insecure but some older browsers (and some
                    // versions of IE) require JSONP to work cross domain
                    // EnableJSONP = true
                    EnableJavaScriptProxies = true,
                    EnableDetailedErrors = true

                };
                // Run the SignalR pipeline. We're not using MapSignalR
                // since this branch already runs under the "/signalr"
                // path.
                map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
            });
        }
    }
}

n of the client that isn't compatible with the server. Client version 1.5, server version undefined.
I have checked the version of signalR in both frontend and backend.
Also, I've tried to add a code block to retry once connection is failed.
One more thing : Most of the time it works, but some times I get this error.

Did you find the problem? I have same error on some clients as: SignalR error: Error: You are using a version of the client that isn't compatible with the server. Client version 2.1, server version undefined.

No, we're now using websocket in place of signalR.
